# Unexpected error with the strtok function with pointers in c

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, strtok

I'm just trying to understand how the `strtok()` function works below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* p="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
    char* q=strtok(p, ",");
    printf("%s", q);

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to run this simple code but I keep getting a weird error that I can't understand at all. 
This is the error I keep getting:

[image: screen shot]

It's probably not relevant but because my command prompt keeps exiting I changed some settings in my project and added this line `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` somewhere and I tried to run the program without debugging at first which didn't even run the program then I tried it with debugging and that's how I got the error in the link.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bas3w.png quite a complex view, I still don't understand how people get used to program in such a complex environment.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
char* p="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
```

use

```
char p[] = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
```

because, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`, it may modify the input string. In your code, the string literal is `read-only`. That's why it produces the segmentation fault.

Related quote:

> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> *
> These functions modify their first argument.

Comment: Good answer, there is no need to enter into too much technicisms.

Answer (score 2):

`char* p="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";` is assigning *read-only* memory to `p`. Really the type of `p` should be `const char*`.

Attempting to change that string in *any* way gives *undefined behaviour*. So using `strtok` on it is a very bad thing to do. To remedy, use

```
char p[]="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
```

That allocates the string on the stack and modifications on it are permitted. `p` *decays* to a pointer in certain instances; one of them being as a parameter to `strtok`.

Comment: I tried this but then I can't use p as a parameter for the strtok function. Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 2):

You may not use string literals with function strtok because the function tries to change the string passed to it as an argument.

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Change this definition

```
char* p="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
```

to

```
char s[] = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
//...
char* q = strtok( s, "," );
```

For example function main can look like

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";
    char* q = strtok( s, "," );

    while ( q != NULL )
    {
        puts( q );
        strtok( NULL, "," );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to solve the error: `Segmentation fault`.
Change `char *p` to `char p[]`.

The reason is because `strtok()` will add `'\0'` the string delimiter when the token character is found. 
In your case `char* p="abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr,stu,vwx,yz";` is stored in read-only section of the program as string literal.

As you are trying to modify a location that is read-only leads to `Segmentation fault`